# How to show the title of the embedded audio file in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, audio

> audio_list(get_the_content())

```
function audio_list($data){

$content    = strip_tags($data);
$audiolist  = explode("[/audio]", $content);
$audiolist  = array_filter($audiolist);
return $audiolist;
```

}

Right now am using a custom function that strip the audio url and split the file name from the url and showing the real file name as the name of the audio in my site. I need to change the real name as media title. How can i do this ?? In word press embedded player media id is not available. In bulk upload case media is not associated with any posts so parent post attachment concept also not working. Do have any other method to get the media title ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the uploaded audio files as an array first

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'audio',
        'numberposts' => -1
    );
    $audiofiles = get_posts($args);
```

create a if condition that matching the file url's

```
foreach ($audiofiles as $file)
{
  $urls = wp_get_attachment_url($file->ID);
  if($urls == 'url from the content'){
      $title = $file->post_title;
  }else {
      $title = 'file real name';
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working only in single file case. If have duplicate upload it is not working perfect.